# Passing Variable as aes reference

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a loop to print a series of plots to separate files in R. Everything works except that when I try to pass a variable to aes in ggplot, the geom_histogram thinks the value is now discrete.

So this works:

```
epdSimpleName <- c("API", "TI", "CE")

for (epdName in epdSimpleName) {
  plot <- ggplot(simpledf, aes(x=API))
  plot <- plot + geom_histogram(binwidth=5)

  print(plot)
}
```

but this does not:

```
epdSimpleName <- c("API", "TI", "CE")

for (epdName in epdSimpleName) {
  plot <- ggplot(simpledf, aes(x=epdName))
  plot <- plot + geom_histogram(binwidth=5)

  print(plot)
}
```

because R thinks that API, TI, etc is then discrete I guess?

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

Thanks for any help/guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the error message is confusing and it doesn't give a good hint about what is wrong.

The example that works specifies the aesthetic as `aes(x = API)`. It is important that `API` is unquoted. The example that doesn't work in effect specifies the aesthetic as `aes(x = "API")` (not explicitly but that's what happens when you cycle through the loop).

So what it is necessary is to take `"API"` and "unquote" it. You can achieve that with `!!rlang::sym("API")`

```r
library("tidyverse")

data(diamonds)

plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x))
plot <- plot + geom_histogram()
print(plot)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
vars <- c("x")

for (var in vars) {
  plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = !!rlang::sym(var)))
  plot <- plot + geom_histogram()
  print(plot)
}
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you! One follow-up question. How could I have figured that out on my own? I knew that the quotes were the problem but could not find the

`!!rlang::sym(var)`
solution.

Thanks again! You rock!

Comment: This is a very big topic. One place to start learning about tidy evaluation and quosures is the vignette "Programming with dplyr": https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html. (Even understanding what these terms mean takes some learning.) I also find this blog summary of common transformations useful: https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/ (You can find this particular transformation under the heading "character to name".)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look!